# Recursive Rails Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion, path, routes

I am using recursive rails path and my route is as follows

```
resources :simplebrowser do
   get '/files/*path', :controller => 'files', :action => 'index'
end
```

and url is

> http://localhost:3000/simplebrowser/:id/files/aaaaa/bbbb/cccc

Is it possible if i append file name at the end of url and it goes to show action. Like

> http://localhost:3000/simplebrowser/:id/files/aaaaa/bbbb/cccc/caledar.war

I want to download the file when above url hits but it keeps on going to index method

Comment: You can also put caledar.war in public folder and use url http://localhost:3000/caledar.war to download the file

Comment: @Abhi this doesn't solve my url structure problem.

Comment: So try this `get '/files/*path/:file_name', :controller => 'files', :action => 'index'` and along with the path created eg:- something_path(:file_name => 'calendar.war'). You need to create similar paths inside your public folder and place the downloadable files

Comment: Use [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) in the controller to start the file download in the browser.

Comment: Let me try this folks. ...

Comment: No luck @ThomasKlemm !

Comment: any other suggestions folks?